# How can I run multiple animations at the same time?

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, runnable

I'm working on a game where objects are dragged and dropped around the screen via touch. I'm doing this using a `SurfaceView`.

Sometimes I need to make an animation to move an object while the user is playing.

This is my code:

```
//raise it 
m = new MyLinearMoveAnimation(container1, Config.AXIS_Y, topLine, 2*Speed);
t = new Thread(m);
t.start();
while(delivering);
try {t.join();} catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
while(t.isAlive());

//move to destination column
m = new MyLinearMoveAnimation(container2, Config.AXIS_X, Config.IMAGE_X, 2*Speed);
t = new Thread(m);
t.start();
while(delivering);
try {t.join();} catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
while(t.isAlive());
```

These two animations are executed one after the other.  I would like for them to both run at the same time.  How can I do this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Comment: they are executed after each other because you're blocking the "parent" thread with while(delivering); and and while(t.isAlive());.

Comment: so can i join() the thread immediatly after ? it will wait thread ends his execution to call join() ? Or i can just remove it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use async task in android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Thanks to async task you can run differents tasks at the same time, if you launch your animations in differents async task they 'll execute in the same tame

Comment: why shoud he/she and how? Include more details so that he/she can understand it very well.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tomorow if i don't find a solution with runnables.